# Is it considered normal to refuse Feedback after rejection on academic positions in EU public funded positions?

Tags: research-process, feedback

I recently applied to the CERN prestigious [Fellowship program](https://jobs.web.cern.ch/job/11857) (Programme des Boursiers). 
A few words on my background: I am a PostDoc in Algorithms/TCS/Network Systems. I have > 10 papers and 2 years of PostDoc experience and I really thought I am a very good fit for that position. I was asked to provide 3 recommendation letters and my advisors where very happy to provide them. I provided a detailed letter on why I consider my expertise fit for the purpose of CERN.

I received a message "*After very careful consideration of your application, we regret to inform you that we are not able to offer you a position at the present time*."

The rejection e-mail did not include absolutely no evaluation information, in the form of a score or text,  as to why my application and my file were rejected. After sending an e-mail to the Recruitment Service, I received the unclear answer that “*we don’t have any personal feedback to give, but this decision in no way reflects your abilities*.” At this point, I kindly protested to this very vague answer for the following reasons:

- This is a job description for highly qualified candidates. It is a common practice, even in private companies, to give a small personal feedback. This serves many purposes, for example to consider the possibility to apply again or not, and also on a personal level so the candidate does not feel completely ignored. Given the profile and the importance of the job, I would have hoped some short explanation based on some evaluation criteria, but absolutely nothing was given to me.
- I still do not know if this is a matter of fitting in the needs of CERN, or that my qualifications were considered low, with respect to the other candidates, or both, or any other reason. I have absolutely no clue regarding whether or not I should considered re-applying to this position in the future.

After that, the Recruitment Service hinted that my profile was not as good as the other candidates, and that “*Fellowship positions cover a wide spectrum of projects and scientific domains for which there are different suitable profiles so the selection criteria can vary depending on the project. Not being selected doesn’t necessarily mean that your qualifications aren’t suitable for CERN but that the projects currently available require different profiles so I encourage you to reapply in the future if you wish to do so*.” At this point, it is natural to ask, which are these mentioned project? Why they were not mentioned in the job description page so I can judge in a better way if I am a good fit or not (and so that the professors that provided the letters and a better clue on what to write to support my application). I asked to provide a complete list of these projects but, unfortunately, the recruitment service decided to completely ignore my request.

- At a relevant point, it is not known to me who is the “Selection Committee” that decided to reject my application. I have no idea on which are these members (and also which are their criteria of acceptance a file).

Given that this is a job offer from a public founded institution, I expect that claims and hints that “The number of post-doctoral applicants exceeds by far the number mentioned in your email and most of them come from distinguished universities around the world with very high qualifications”, that directly hints that my qualifications are low with respect to other candidates, **to be supported by concrete evidence, otherwise this directly raises an issue of transparency**, which is of the utmost importance in such public institutions.

Still, I have no clue (among other things) on how I compare with the selected candidates both in fitting and in qualifications.

The Recruitment Service wrote that “ *Transparency is a value highly appreciated at CERN so if you have any more questions don’t hesitate to come back to me.*” After I raised my particular and above mentioned issues, my queries were completely ignored, so this statement made by your service is completely worthless.

- A more serious issue is that the 3 professors that provided me recommendation letters ask me why I was not selected and I do not have any answer to give them. I invested a respectable amount of obligation by asking these people to support my application so I assume that they deserve an answer for the decision. By not giving any feedback, either on the personal or on the professional level, these people will hesitate to provide again the same letters for a potential future application for obvious reasons.
- The Recruitment Service politely encouraged me to re-apply “if I wish to do so”. I wonder, how it would be possible a rejected candidate to re-apply when crucial information is hidden from that candidate. How can I convince the professors that provided the recommendation letters to re-write them, when they have absolutely no clue on the criteria imposed by the selection committee and on the particular projects (that the committee decided that I am not a good fit for)? How could I improve my file and my CV so I can increase my chances? This is crucial and important information that your Organization decided, deliberately or not, to hide from me.

Unfortunately, 3 or more weeks after the rejection letter I was in complete dark as to why my application was rejected and which are the criteria of acceptance/rejection of the application (among other issues raised above). By just sending  extremely vague and multi-purpose messages, that seemed completely automated to me, the service thought that they fulfilled their obligation. But given the profile of the job and the nature of the organization, I am afraid that these practices are not in due course with what is expected from an International Public Founded Organization.

Personally, I consider these issues extremely important for me, on a personal development level, as well as for CERN.

- After that, I sent an official complaint to the HR department of CERN. I told them that I am willing to publish my experience with CERN so that everybody knows the treatment that I have received from such an international and public institution that takes pride from it's scientific discoveries.

3 weeks after sending the letter, I received an e-mail from an HR responsible person saying "*After reviewing your application in detail and bringing your concerns to the attention of the Chair of the Fellows committee, I am able to inform you that the major weakness in your application was in its motivation. I stress that you were applying for a programme and not for a specific position. There is a huge amount of information about CERN, its activities, and the kinds of projects we do available on the CERN web site. We consider it essential that a candidate has informed themselves, and can show how their research is linked to the research at CERN. Unfortunately, you did not demonstrate that you had tried to inform yourself of our mission and activities and did not explain how your proposed research in applied mathematics could be relevant.*"

Right...

**My Question:** Is the behaviour of CERN normal? Is it OK (from a transparency point of view) that I have no clue who the Committee was, even after many mails exchanging? Is it normal that even after requested a list of successful candidates, I still have no info about it, so I can personally compare myself to the profiles of those they are accepted? Is it normal that still I have absolutely no clue about their selection criteria (besides the "motivation" part, which seems just like a poor excuse to me)?

**EDIT** most of the people confuse this situation with the admission system in US Universities. The situation is slightly more different in EU. For all public calls and openings, there should be a record of who applied, what are the criteria, how individuals scored under these well defined and known criteria and who was selected. This is true in virtually ALL European countries. I (apparently wrongly) assumed that I should be given at least a minimal feedback **and** information (that should be nevertheless available) on how I scored and which are the criteria, so that I could see if I could apply or not, on next round. The answer that I have received (after some mail exchanged and after stating that I would publicize my experience) does not satisfy me the slightest and seems just an arbitrary excuse to "get rid" of me. It saddens me that these practices are going to go unaffected and people at CERN can continue their, seemingly, arbitrary hiring process, not being accountable to anybody.

Comment: "Story of my life" questions are not very appropriate for the SE format. Consider asking a more general question on what is the normal level of feedback to be expected in the academic job market after a rejection. Otherwise, chances are that people won't even read your question till the end.

Comment: You are clearly upset. But, you have received feedback. Did it help you? You seem to believe it did not. What level of feedback are you expecting? A long detailed letter? I have had to go through a hundred applications for one position - it is a long slog with decisions made pretty quickly.

Comment: Lack of motivation (or, better: context-setting) is a pretty strong reason for rejection. Most advisors for job applicants nowadays make clear that putting into context how the applicant's application fits into the overall position advertisement is a core requirement. The response seems to indicate that the application lacked in this respect. Tone and mood of above question (apart from it being far too long) indicate that the OP also sets unrealistic expectations on the job selectors and undue importance to their own application. CERN will see *a lot* of highly qualified applicants. Cont'd.

Comment: The behaviour of public institutions during a selection process is frequently regulated by a country's law, but I don't know if there are specific laws applicable to international institutions like CERN. In my experience, the feedback in selection processes is frequently kept to a minimum level, and I would consider CERN's behaviour as normal. Further information could be probably obtained by filing some kind of formal complaint against CERN, but it's not something I'd suggest doing.

Comment: Frankly, the demanding tone of above question would raise a red flag with an employer if it shone through during the feedback request (of course, the OP may just be venting here on SE). I know of cases where an applicant rejected in the first round was accepted at a later advertisement round, or cases where the rejected applicant later collaborated from outside with the group that rejected him; however, I would have thought it unlikely that this would have happened if the applicant would have radiated a sense of entitlement during the procedure, even if technically being in the right.

Comment: It is *absolitely not* common practice to give "small personal feedback" when interviewing in industry. I failed to get into Goldman Sachs about 2 or 3 times. In no case did I receive official feedback, only through a friend at GS. Had a I berserked after any of these rejections though like you appear to have, I wouldn't even have gotten one second chance. Also, we (my firm) did not provide helpful feedback either. It's a litigation risk, if nothing else. Asking for constructive feedback once is fine ("Anything I can do better?"), but you take whatever comes back, and shut up.

Comment: For all the commenters so far: What I initially wanted was a tiny feedback: I do not consider it such an unrealistic request. They rejected me because they evaluated my dossier as inadequate. I was very VERY politely asking for a minimal evaluation of my dossier. I consider it illogical that I had to go through a VERY lengthy process to get "lack of motivation" that does not convince me (but that's personal). I did NOT want to challenge their decision.

Comment: @PsySp In your story, could you make explicit how many exchanges between you and CERN happened in total (apart from the original application and the original response)? It was hard to follow, but it looked as if there were quite a few. You say you did not want to challenge their decision, but if there was more than one more exchange, that's how it will have looked to them. With - likely - several hundred applications, CERN will have to assume that perhaps 5% or more (it is a very competitive field) will have thoughts about challenging the decision. For 200 applicants, that'd be 10 appeals.

Comment: Put yourself in the shoes of the people reading applications. They have way too many applicants to give personalized feedback to each one. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs: My initial intent was to send a single mail asking IF there is a possibility for potential feedback. After receiving a message that considered completely automated to me, I exchanged 2 more with them, till finally I contacted the HR where they answered me about "lack of motivation". I sincerely and explicitly did not want to challenge their decision (I already got another good PostDoc position). Just, I get rather frustrated with their attitude. And my questions were simple: which are the criteria, which is the committee and who are the successful applicants

Comment: @ user37208
I did not ask for much: just the evaluation matrix of my dossier (they should have a rather simple matrix giving scores to applicants). In the case I wanted to re-apply, I wanted to know, if possible, what I did wrong (if I did any, maybe just too many good applicants!)

Comment: @PsySP In some countries, the criteria must be clearly delineated in the official application material. Not sure whether this is the case for CERN; but this is a reasonable request (although would have been more useful beforehand). The committee usually need not to be known beforehand, but typically the information is auditable. It is nevertheless a question that, from a candidate, creates a strange impression. Finally, as who has been selected: this question would be *entirely out of order*; this is strictly confidential until the candidates take up the post or choose to divulge it.

Comment: @ CaptainEmacs: Come to my position. They hint that I was not good enough (based on which criteria??). All my 3 professors asked me why I was not selected, I had nothing to answer to them. This feels humiliating. I asked about the committee afterwards, and still I have no clue. There should be some public record afterwards about the successful candidates. After all it is a public institution and they are payed by tax-payers money. If it was GOOGLE  I couldn't care less. But it's "funny" when there are NO selection criteria to criticize motivation (after a lengthy cover letter...)

Comment: @PsySp Many here at SE *have* been in your position. Many here have applied to positions at some point and often not even heard back, not even so much as a short rejection. Even not from publicly funded institutions. The fact that your references ask you about your application shows they care about you - but this may have also created undue pressure on you to justify not being taken. There are a lot of highly talented people out there, with supportive mentors. I am sorry for your position, but it's more typical than not. If you are as talented as you imply, you will find something good soon.

Comment: @PsySp However, I strongly recommend to take such rejections in stride. If they cause you - even in the heat of the moment - to cross the line (as e.g. asking about who has been selected, which is none of your business), you'll end up raising more red flags than a Soviet October parade. For the future: if unclear, try to clarify the selection criteria beforehand and: Good Luck!

Comment: @Captain Emacs. First of all, thanks for the constructive comments. 2nd, it's not about the rejection, it's about the attitude. In my opinion there is something really shady there, otherwise they would not have absolutely no reason to hide very relevant information. It is important, in public affairs, everything to be on display and being judged and criticized (in constructive way). I did not imply I was good, It's up to others to judge me, according to well define and applicable to all criteria. Just, as a European tax-payer I expect a little bit more transparency from them.

Comment: For all hiring, not just academic, there may be more candidates who are good enough to justify hiring them than there are open positions. Candidate A is the best fit for a position. If A had not applied, Candidate B would have been selected. There is no way to explain the decision to B without revealing confidential information about A.

Comment: From the same side: I've been rejected from literally hundreds of academic jobs in my life (mainly in the US, many public).  None has offered any feedback whatsoever.  I'd have been really grateful to have as much information as you got in the email you did receive - it's a bit harsh, but it points out a weakness they perceived in your application, which you evidently didn't notice yourself.  You may feel you are entitled to more information, but the fact is that the standards of the academic community don't agree.

Comment: According to your words, you were accepted to 1-2 postdoc positions. Did you make sure that those who got rejected for the same positions, received the feedback you demand? Probably not. If not, wasn't it unethical on your part to accept a position on an institute that did not meet your high ethical standards? Or ethical obligations only apply to your rejections?

Comment: @Alexnadros. I am asking IF it is a common practice when you ASK for relevant Feedback/selection criteria that are UNKNOWN on a publicly appointed position, to get denied access to relevant information. Otherwise it raised issues of transparency. Your comment does not make much sense I am afraid.

Comment: **If you mean to ask a question specifically about European academia, please make that restriction prominently in the question (ideally, in the title) and add an appropriate tag.**

Comment: Could you provide some reference for the facts stated about European positions and admission? I have never heard of anything as structured as that, especially the scoring part (except for some stories from Italian universities which were mainly used to highlight how absurd the bureaucracy has become). Also, I was certainly not aware of anything like a public record of who applied, though I may just have nevr bothered to find such.

Comment: @Tobias On the top of my head: here is the list of accepted PhDs at the graduate program of my former university (in Greece) + individual info for some of the candidates http://www.cs.uoi.gr/upFiles/uploads/06_01_2016_13-09-17.pdf  Moreover, look at the complete info and evaluation on the pdf of the following document  https://diavgeia.gov.gr/decision/view/7%CE%9C%CE%A3%CE%92469%CE%927%CE%97-4%CE%A6%CE%A7 for publicly appointed position at the same university (by the Greek law, everything must be posted online on that site. Diavgeia means "transparency")

Comment: That does not really answer my question. You claimed this as something required on a European scale, not in specific European countries. And there is a big difference between a list of accepted PhD's and a list of who applied to the PhD.

Comment: Check the 2nd link. According to the Greek law, it is a requirement. I thought that Greek law is on the same lines with the European one (isn't it? I am not a lawyer)

Comment: The second link is entirely in Greek, so I have no way to know what to look for (and how do they ensure transparency by having everything in Greek anyway?). And since you are talking about an application at CERN, I assumed that you would at least have something related to the laws there (no idea if the relevant things would be EU law or ones more local).

Comment: This was an example but you can clearly see the evaluation matrix. Since these are publically appointed positions in Greek universities (Greek citizenship required afaik) it makes sense to be written in the local language. That was basically the core of my question: What info can be legally be given away? What are the actual laws in these situations? In what law system the CERN regulations fall in? I am certainly not aware, and this is the reason of my questions. My experiences probably "misguided" me but I still believe it's a matter worth figuring out.

Comment: "The situation is slightly more different in EU. For all public calls and openings, there should be a record of who applied, what are the criteria, how individuals scored under these well defined and known criteria and who was selected. This is true in virtually ALL European countries"

Hm. I have a completely opposite situation (theoretical physics). All the EU universities who refused my postdoc applications did not send even a formal email, so the only way to get any information was to look at "postdoc rumor mill".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, as someone who is a professor and university department chair (in the U.S.) and who is directly involved with recruitment processes, I can tell you that it is normal and, at least according to currently accepted norms, ethical. I can't address your complaints in detail, but you seem to be very misguided about many of your beliefs concerning academic recruitment processes, how they are and should be carried out, and how you as a job candidate should be treated. A few points that I think need to be clarified are the following:

- Academic employers are not required to, and often have strong legal incentives not to, provide any feedback to applicants about their applications.
- I am not aware of, and have never even heard of, any academic employer who uses an "evaluation matrix" or anything similar for a recruitment to an academic position at the postdoc level or higher. Evaluation for these positions doing very specialized kinds of research is highly subjective, with different applicants often being completely incomparable to each other in almost any imaginable parameter, and often members of the search committee and other academics participating in the search may disagree strongly about the ranking of applicants. Somehow, a decision is eventually reached, but there is a lot of arbitrariness in the process, which is something that (as I have witnessed on many occasions) is often hard for the people on the other end of the process to accept.
- Even if the evaluation was less subjective and arbitrary and truly meaningful feedback could in theory be provided, in many cases the sheer number of applicants can make it completely impractical to respond to each one individually with this kind of feedback. Imagine being an overworked search committee chair having to review something like 700-800 application files (each one containing 30-40 pages of materials) to fill 3-5 positions, and you may start seeing what I mean. That is why many search committees will not even send rejected applicants an email notification to tell them they were not selected.
- There is absolutely no reason for you to feel humiliated or embarrassed by not having feedback to relay to your letter-writers. If they are experienced academics, they must know that this is how the system works and will not be expecting any such information, or even if they are then surely they will understand that you cannot be blamed for not receiving such information to relay to them.

To conclude, I should add that there is nonetheless a kernel of philosophical, and perhaps legal, truth in your complaint and frustration. It is true that it is regrettable that employers can't offer job applicants useful feedback that helps them calibrate their approach and perhaps do better in the future, and having been in similar situations myself in the past, I certainly empathize, but that's how things currently stand. It is also true that having such a low level of accountability creates an opening for abuse of various sorts, which I'm sure does in fact exist in some places. Legally speaking, in some countries job applicants may have certain rights to demand disclosure of at least some of the information you ask for, either through filing a request or, in an extreme situation where they feel they have been gravely wronged, by filing a lawsuit. Even when the information is not provided, employers will often keep on record some information of this type for use in the event that they are called upon to defend their hiring decisions. My university certainly does. You may want to look into what legal rights you have and see if you have in fact treated in accordance with the law in your jurisdiction. At the same time, I think you need to understand that your current views about how much feedback you should be entitled to get are misguided and, frankly speaking, mostly wrong. In any case, good luck and I hope you have more success with future applications.

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful comment. Technically, you are of course 100% right. A few points: I was in fact encouraged by my references to ask for any potential feedback. I did not want to challenge any decision (in the meantime I was offered a very good position). Just I was very surprised to receive, what I perceive, arbitrary answers for a job without clearly defined criteria, that my file "seemed" appropriate according to the high level description of the job. I sincerely put a lot of effort for that application and I -wrongly- thought I deserved a bit of an answer.

Comment: @PsySp I understand. You did nothing wrong by asking for feedback, and as I said you have nothing to feel embarrassed about. You are in the same boat as (probably) hundreds of applicants, many of whom are like you very hardworking and talented. Anyway, glad you found my answer useful, and congrats on the position you ended up getting.

Comment: Thank you for your message. I would also like to add that prior my CERN application, I was probably "spoiled" in the sense that I was rejected by 1 PostDoc positions and 2 industry ones (both as research scientists on big corporations as Yahoo) and in all these 3 cases I have received actual feedback on why my application was unsuccessful, which actually helped me in my future steps. I was wrongly expecting something similar from a public institution, and this "magnified" my surprise on their behaviour

Comment: @PsySp: Based on what you write, you currently hold a postdoc position and are/were applying for another one...and you have only been rejected from **one other postdoc position**?  I am flabbergasted by this.  In my experience, people apply for postdocs 20-100 or so at a time...of course because there is such a high rejection rate.  Have you really not applied for any other postdocs at public institutions?

Comment: The situation outside the US might be quite different. In Spain, for instance, all academic positions are awarded after a formally appointed commission scores the applications according to purportedly objective criteria. In most cases who the candidates are is published officially, the candidate rankings and scores are published, and the candidate evaluations are usually available upon formal request or formal protest. Similar systems are in place in much of Europe. Someone coming from such a system could find a typical US job application process opaque.

Comment: @DanFox: that was exactly my point! This was what I expected and asked for and what I did NOT get (not even mildly). Thus my question. People judged my question based, mostly, on the US system of admission.

Comment: @Pete L. Clark What can I say. I was finishing my 1st PostDoc and was looking for the next career step, thus my applications. After the CERN rejection I, thankfully, was offered another PostDoc appointment, which I took without hesitation. At a side note, not to my surprise, my 2nd appointment was much more transparent than the CERN one. Still, nobody knows what are the criteria of CERN and why they refuse access to information that *should* be otherwise publicly available.

Comment: @PsySp: That was what I imagined was the situation. Many of those posting here seem insufficiently aware of the radical differences in mentality underlying academic systems in different countries. Many of the practices regarded as normal in the US are considered problematic in other countries, the use of recommendation letters being a prime example.

Comment: @DanFox. I hope all of the people posted here (I guess primarily from the US) understand that for us, Europeans, it's somewhat "shocking" such a behaviour, especially when it comes from a public institution like CERN. We are much more sensitive in public administration issues. Anyway, unfortunately it seems that nothing is going to change. People suggest "deal with it", "it's how it is" and CERN can continue their unreasonable and arbitrary (to me) practices of hiring that are the opposite of meritocracy. Caesar's wife must be above suspicion.

Comment: @DanRomik Great response.

Comment: @PsySp you have a right to be shocked, but empirically CERN's recruitment policies are similar to what we see in the US, not to what you imagine should happen in Europe. Respectfully, even considering DanFox's comments I stand by my opinion that you are quite misguided about your belief that you deserve to get feedback. Your statement "We are much more sensitive in public administration issues" is also patently false, for many reasons I have no room to discuss. Administration in US academia is generally very ethical and well-functioning, certainly at least as much as in Europe.

Comment: @DanRomik. I have no experience about US public administration, besides the comments received here and have no reason to believe that something is not ethical. Everybody seemed to judge the situation based on what happens in US, but this might not be the correct approach since CERN is based in Europe. Anyway, I agree with all your comments (and I thank you for them) I just try to make my case from my point of view and my current experiences. In any case my statement ""much more sensitive.." is a crude exaggeration and I retract it. I apologise!

Comment: @PsySp Speaking as someone trained in the UK system, who now works in the UK system, and who knows people working in the European academic system (in mathematics) I would like to say that your comments "I hope all of the people posted here (I guess primarily from the US) understand that for us, Europeans, it's somewhat "shocking" such a behaviour" are _extremely presumptuous_. I have refrained from commenting on your post, but can only say that even when I was seeking my first permanent job I did not share your attitude nor your expectations

Comment: @PsySp In short: please don't make this into a USA vs non-USA issue. I have worked in both North America and the UK and am aware of some differences. This, in my view is **not one of them**, and -- let me completely blunt -- I find the sense of entitlement in your whole post quite striking, regardless of whether you were fairly or unfairly treated by those to whom you applied.

Comment: @Yemon Choi Probably my expectations, based on my experiences so far, are wrong. Thus the question, because I wanted to clarify in my head what is normal and what is not. Otherwise I wouldn't have asked. I tried to analyse why I had the attitude. I would never have this attitude for _any_ academic job but I thought that more appropriate criteria should apply in this particular case. I did not want to put CERN and any other academic job in the same bag. Probably that's false, and I should have treated it as everything else.

Comment: @Yemon Choi Maybe my tone _seems_ demanding but in all honesty it is not. I am sorry if my tone failed to communicate my message.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark While it is certainly not the norm that people end up rejected from only a few positions, it must happen for at least a few (if nothing else because occasionally there will be an "off-season" posting that someone gets even though it is the first place they apply), and questions about this sort of thing is more likely to come precisely from someone with less experience from rejections (as a comparison, I only got rejected from 3 or 4 positions before getting my current one, so low numbers do happen even in math).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I think that is basically the reason of "misunderstanding" thus the question. It was certainly the first time that such info was disclosed, something that was very different from my experiences so far. This together with the encouragement from my references to try to get any info, if possible, led to that situation. I wanted to know what is the norm. It seems that my few previous experiences were the exception and not the rule. At the same time, It would be nice to know what info _can_ in principle be legally obtained (I would definitely not go to extreme measures).

Answer (score 20):

### Yes, this is considered both normal and ethical.

Perhaps the most salient reason is that hiring/admissions decisions are based on direct comparisons between applicants, and application materials are strictly confidential.  If my department doesn't hire you, we are forbidden to tell you that it's because we thought X, Y, and Z were better fits for the position — although that might very well be the precise reason — because **we are forbidden to reveal who applied for the position**.  Of course, you might eventually notice that we eventually hired Y, but we are forbidden reveal Y's application materials, *especially* their reference letters, which we can't even reveal to Y.

(I'm deliberately using "better fit" to encapsulate all the metrics that people use to make hiring/admission decisions: GPA, standardized test scores, research statements, recommendation letters, teaching experience, publication and citation records, awards, specific research interests/skills/results, "pedigree", constraints imposed by funding agencies or university bureaucrats, demonstrated familiarity with the institution, behavior at the interview, and so on.  Ultimately, **every academic hiring decision is a judgement call**; there isn't and can't be a hiring algorithm.)

We *could* legally say "Other applications were a better fit for the position than yours", but that's a rather obvious conclusion from the fact that we didn't hire you, and we're legally forbidden to provide evidence to back up that reasoning.  If you don't find that explanation satisfying, there's really nothing we can do.

Another reason is that direct criticism in this context is just considered *rude*.  The academic job market is highly competitive; for almost all applicants, most applications end in rejection.  Unlike publications, where brutally honest feedback *on the work* is a necessary part of the process, critical feedback on your application is really about **you**, or at least your professional persona.  Direct personal criticism, no matter how accurate, is much more likely to lead to hurt feelings (as demonstrated by your post) and possibly even lawsuits than criticism of any specific piece of work.  (This argument is sometimes oversimplified as "[CYA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_your_ass)".)

The right people to give you direct critical feedback on your application are your advisor and/or close senior colleagues, not your prospective employers.

> A more serious issue is that the 3 professors that provided me recommendation letters ask me why I was not selected and I do not have any answer to give them.

Actually, you have at least two reasonable answers:

- "I don't know."
- "What? Why are *you* asking *me*?  You know these people better than I do!"

> How could I improve my file and my CV so I can increase my chances?

Do better research.  Publish better papers.  Give better talks.  Apply to more positions.  Get brutally honest feedback on your application from your advisor and other experienced colleagues, and take that criticism seriously.  Contact colleagues at your target institutions *in advance* to get a clearer picture of their needs, goals, and culture.

Accept that you will not, and cannot, have complete information about hiring criteria at any particular institution; you can only increase your chances *on average across the field*.  Accept that neither you nor anyone else *deserves* any particular position.

> *Unfortunately, you did not demonstrate that you had tried to inform yourself of our mission and activities and did not explain how your proposed research in applied mathematics could be relevant.*

Your response ("Right.") suggests that you don't find this explanation credible.  That is a very serious mistake.

[I am the recruiting committee chair at a highly-ranked computer science department, at a public university in the U.S.  Our hiring processes are scrutinized to ensure compliance with state and federal employment laws, in particular: (1) that we have a fair, consistent, and *internally* well-documented decision process, and (2) that applications are strictly confidential.]

Comment: "we're legally forbidden to provide evidence to back up that reasoning": in certain countries (mine, for instance) an applicant can formally ask to review the proceedings of a public selection process, which should contain the assessments of the candidates as given by the committee. Sometimes, this is the first step toward an appeal against the committee's decision. However, as I stated in a comment above, even if  this were possible in the OP's case, I would advise against such a request.

Comment: Additional possible answer to the references: "I don't know. Do you have time to review my application to see if you have any ideas?"

Comment: @Patricia Shanaha. I was in fact encouraged by my references to ask for feedback, if any of course. My file seemed "technically sound".

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I don't consider tht a reasonable answer, because _of course_ OP already asked for that feedback before applying.

Comment: @JeffE. Thank you for your answer, for which I mostly agree. The point is that for public appointments there should be *some* public record (as Massimo points out and that was the point of my post). Also for the last point: I did not find their explanation credible: I spent a lot of effort and time for that application, and on writing a lengthy cover letter on why and how I fit in CERN's missions. Sorry, for me sounded as a cheap excuse since they have nothing better to say. And my references certainly agree with that view (in fact they all had the same reaction when I told them: laugh...)

Comment: Hopefully you tailored your actual application, and not just your cover letter.  But in any case, how much effort and time you put into the application Does Not Matter; all that matters is whether they were convinced.  Their reply is probably polite-code for "We were not convinced by your explanation of how your proposed research is relevant." or more simply, "We don't think your proposed research is relevant."